# Get Page post notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hei,

I am wondering if this is possible:

I have a page of my own where I occasionally post. What I want is that when ever I post something facebook does a POST to a url of my choice.

I guess real time updates for pages in the graph API would let me achieve this ? am I right?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime

If so then how do I do this ? I have been trying to make sense of it but I don't seem to be able to get it working. I created an app but I don't understand how to connect the dots together here.

In my app's Real Time updates panel I have create a subscription for object 'Page' for fields 'feed', I have specified callback url as well. But now I am confused on how to connect the app with the page ?
Even though I have made the app a 'page tab' app but I can not find out a way to add the app to my page's tab ??

please help !

-A

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime